# Why does "echo !!!0" output as 1?

Tags: php

i couldn't understand why i am getting the output "1" from the below statement in PHP,

```
<?php echo !!!0;?>
```

please let me know the reason

Comment: Why wouldn't you be?

Comment: lol very low quality question.

Comment: I don't think so. Understanding such things is very important.

Comment: The key is to realize `echo true` is "1" and *not* "true". With that in mind, the non-understood output is quickly stripped away revealing expected behavior. (So I disagree that it's a "bad" question, just mostly a red-herring with how the output is understood.)

Comment: You are printing `true`, so you get `1` displayed, use `var_dump`/`print_r` to see true type of variable

Comment: @Johni Yes but refer to the php documentation for that. I voted for the question being offtopic..

Comment: But let me ask you what do you expect as the output @Sadiq

Comment: IMHO this question is appropriate because it is hard to find the solution by google. What keywords would you search for to find an answer?

Comment: @DanFromGermany don't you think it's too basic to be asked here? I mean, not not not false would be true.. why not? How hard is it to understand?

Comment: @noc2spamツ: nothing is too basic to be asked on stackoverflow

Comment: @knittl I'm not *so* sure about that.. but this question does meet the requirements as far as I am concerned, with provided code and output. (It would be better if the OP reasoned about what his/her expected output was though.)

Comment: negate negate negate... Now try echo 010; :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The statement is parsed as `!(!(!0))`. `!` is the logical negation operator. When applying it to any other type than a boolean (true/false), the operand is first cast to a boolean value (0, empty string, empty array, null, empty SimpleXML objects = false; everything else true).

Let's break the statement down:

```
!!!0 ==
!!!false ==
!!true ==
!false ==
true
```

Finally, `echo true` will output `1`.

Comment: +1 as this is the *only* current answer that correctly identifies why the result is "1"; it is due to `echo` and not the negation operator.

Comment: The statement that everything else than 0 is true is wrong. There are other falsy values: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: @ComFreek: well. Technically true (no pun intended), but for numerical values it's correct. Have updated my answer to include the other false-y values.

Answer (score 3):

Because PHP "casts" the 0 to a boolean when doing a logic operation.

So !0 is 1
!1 is 0
!0 is 1

Comment: The result of `!0` *is* true, not 1. Check with: `!0 === true` (true) and `!0 === 1` (false).

Comment: I wrote it as echo would output is. Yes, before outputting it, it's a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

`!` is used to negate statements (post-evaluated).

```
0 evaluates to false => true (1) => false (0) => true (1)
                        !           !            !
```

Why is a number cast to boolean?

This happens implicitly by using `!`, the exclamation mark expects yes `true` or no `false` and so the value next to it gets automatically cast to something that fits this condition (yes or no).

You can make similiar experiments using:

```
var_dump( !"hello world" );
//   ...
```

Explicit casts are done by putting the type in brackets: `(boolean)1 === true`

Update for @user2864740:

```
<?php
var_dump(!0 === true);    // bool(true)
var_dump(!(0) === true);  // bool(true)
var_dump((!0) === true);  // bool(true)
var_dump((boolean)1 === true); // bool(true)
var_dump((boolean)1); // bool(true)
```

Update after discussion:

`echo true;` prints `1`. But this does not change a variable for example:

```
$x = true;
echo $x; // 1
var_dump($x); // bool(true)
```

Comment: This is misleading as `true === 1` is false. The result of `!!!0` *is* true, not 1.

Comment: @user2864740 no you are wrong: `<?php
var_dump((boolean)1 === true); // bool(true)
var_dump((boolean)1); // bool(true)` - please don't downvote until you verified your comment

Comment: Check with this: `if (!0 === 1) echo "equals 1"; else "not equals 1";`. The conversion to "1" happens *because of echo* (see `echo true`) and not due to the negation operator.

Comment: @user2864740 I did not say `1 === true`, I said `(boolean)1 === true` - that's a difference

Comment: The statement `0 evaluates to false => true (1) => false (0) => true (1)` is misleading at best: true is not 1, false is not 0. The "1" in the output come from and *only* from `echo`.

Comment: When you negate 0, it gets cast to boolean by the `!`, please VERIFY your comment (using php codepad for example) before starting a discussion.

Comment: Please refer to the previous comments. I have said nothing *against* casting. I have said that the statements made about `false (0)` and `true (1)` are wrong, as false and true are *not* numbers. I agree *with* casting/coercion of numbers in negations as `!0 === true` *is* true - this is not what I am arguing against. However, `!0 === 1` *is* still wrong, and implications that this causes the "1" in the output is also wrong (the results of `echo "1"`, `echo 1`, `echo true` are all "1").

Comment: You edit all of your comments after I replied. After rereading, you are right with the point when `echo true` outputs `1`, there is another implicit cast made by `echo` but that's just "visually" and doesn't effect a variable's type (see the last 3 lines of the answer).